# For-loop condition conventions

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, conditional-statements, conventions

I had recently a discussion about the use of non-counter related conditions in for-loops in Java:

```
for(int i = 0; o.getC() < 10; i++)
    o.addC(i);
```

Does anyone know if there are any "official" conventions for for-conditions like this? In my opinion it's easier to read compared to an equivalent while-loop because all loop-parameters are together in the first line:

```
int i = 0;
while(o.getC() < 10) {
    i++;
    o.addC(i);
}
```

Or even worse:

```
int i = 0;
while(o.getC() < 10)
    o.addC(++i);
```

Comment: What do you mean by non-counter related conditions? This for is definitely counter related.

Comment: The for loop is preferably (IMO) because 1) `i` is scoped to the loop; 2) you are forced to remember to increment (or explicitly not increment) `i` on each iteration. The second and third options here add no particular advantage, and are less readable (esp the `o.addC(++i);`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when to use while loop rather than for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710601/when-to-use-while-loop-rather-than-for-loop)

Comment: With counter-related condition I mean a condition that evaluates the counter-variable directly like `i < 10`

Comment: Do you know all parts of the for are optional? `for (;;)` is equivalent to `while (true)`. So, the only "convention" is that is needs to be a condition, but evaluates to true if excluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loops are used in pretty much every situation over equivalent `while` solution. Arrays, lists, standard data structures.

On the other hand `while` is commonly used with streams and for infinitely long iterations..

Answer (score 1):

Most developers will expect a `for` statement to consist of three things:

- Initialization of a variable
- Termination condition based on the variable
- Increment on the variable

If you change your code to contain unexpected things it will get harder to read and thus harder to maintain.

Furthermore, I think the `while` loop makes your intention clearer: *do something while `o.getC()` is less then 10*. This "something" happens to be: *add an incrementing number*.

Long story short: use a `while` loop for "non-counter related conditions".

Answer (score 0):

A nice thing about for loops is there is a shortcut method. So if you want to do all of the items in an array you can just do the following:

(double number : arrayName)
where double is the type, number is the name you are giving each element (it doesn't matter really what you call it, you will refer to each value there as "number" in this case). And arrayName is the name of the array you are referring to.

If you want to reach each element/object this is the fastest way.

Comment: It's called an enhanced for loop. (I call it a foreach loop). And actually, it isn't the "fastest" in terms of speed because under the hood it has to do type conversions and still uses a regular for loop.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I'm a new programmer myself. Was trying to help however I could :p

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATIONS; i++)
{
    o.addC(i);
    if (o.getC() >= 10)
        return o; // or break
}
```

This prevents an infinite loop if addC is not really doing what you expect.