# Counting iterations

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

So this is the question: Determine how many iterations of the following operation are required until the condition (a * a + b * b) > 4 is reached:

newA = a * a - b * b + x

newB = 2 * a * b + y

a = newA

b = newB

I have been stuck on this for a while. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 public static int findEscapeCount(double x, double y, int maxIterations)
{
    int count =0;
    double a;
    double b;
    double newA;
    double newB;

    for(a=0; a<maxIterations; a++)
    {
        for(b=0; b<maxIterations; b++)
        {
            newA = a * a - b * b + x;
            newB = 2 * a * b + y;
            a = newA;
            b = newB;

            if((a * a + b * b) < 4)
            {
                count = count+1;    

            }

       }

    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Fix indenting. What is the output you are getting?

Comment: Lighten up, @JoeC, the OP posted his/her code.  It's a legitimate request.

Comment: you should use a single while loop to check the condition of (a * a + b * b) < 4 and increment a & b each iteration.  then keep a count of iterations.  it will automatically exit when the condition is met and your count will be correct.

Comment: I didn't provide what my output is. When x and y are both equal to 1, I get an output of 1 when it should be 2 for example. I will try to do what you said @big_water thanks for the advice.

Comment: And thanks @nicomp,  Im not trying to copy and paste code for an answer Im trying to get help.

Comment: @JonahBartz, the main thing to take away here is the difference between "for" loops and "while" loops and how/where to use each one.  it can be confusing at first. decent explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6710635/5481661

Comment: @JonahBartz This place is becoming elitist. Your question was fine. Your indenting was awful. ;)

Comment: Im still new to programing. Id much rather have indenting problems than wrong output ;) Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, this should be along the lines of what you need:

```
public static int findEscapeCount(double x, double y, int maxIterations)
{
   int count =0;
   double a;
   double b;
   double newA;
   double newB;


   while((a * a + b * b) > 4)
   {
      a++;
      b++;

      newA = a * a - b * b + x;
      newB = 2 * a * b + y;
      a = newA;
      b = newB;

      count++;

   }

   return count;

}
```

**EDIT:** after re-reading the question, I'm not even sure if incrementing "a" and "b" each iteration is necessary as you are re-assigning them each iteration anyways... but you'll have to determine that from your requirements!

Comment: The thing is though I need to provide a max number of iterations. So if after that max time the condition still isn't met than the answer is the given number of max iterations. Im not sure how to do that in a while loop.

Comment: you can check the "count" variable with an "if" statement and if it is equal to "maxIterationCount", then break out of the while loop with a "break;" statement and return the count

Comment: I switched the 'greater' than to 'less than' and tried this and it still isn't correct. Im not sure why this seems like it would work. It returns 1 every time no matter the argument.

Comment: @JonahBartz I think you want to keep it as greater than in this case. Isn't that the condition in your question?

Comment: @JonahBartz, what numbers are you using for the input to the function (x and y)

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. I took out the a++ and the b++ because they are getting new values every loop and it works beautifully. THANK YOU SO MUCH. @big_water

Comment: @JonahBartz, you're welcome.  I suggested that in the edit I did right after I posted the answer.  I guess I should've pointed that out.  Please mark the answer as accepted if your question is answered.  thank you