# How to make for and while loops in Python to get the same answer?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

this is my very first time asking a question on StackOverflow!

I am trying to write a code to know at what natural number the accumulated sum to the number becomes right before 10,000 using for and while loops in python.

a for loop,

```
accum_sum = 0
for n in range(10000):
if accum_sum > 10000:
   print(n-1)
   break
```

it gave me 140

and I was wondering how to write a code to get the same thing(140) by using a while loop ... this is what I tried but somehow it gave me a different answer. Can someone help me with this? I feel like I am lost

```
accum_sum = 0
while accum_sum < 10000:
n += 1
accum_sum = accum_sum + n
if accum_sum > 10000:
    print(n-1)
    break
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think you forgot to post some of your code. Your first snippet never adds to `accum_sum`, so it will always be zero

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: your comment and @hwhap's answer helped me where I made mistakes- I fixed the snippet part and finally it worked out the way I wanted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code snippets:

- As [@canton7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1086121/canton7) pointed out, in *for* you are never adding num to accum_sum and hence it will always be zero
- n is not defined before *while*, so you cannot increment it by 1 and will be thrown a NameError

Changing these and adding appropriate indentation should give you something like below.

Using for:

```
   sum = 0
   for num in range(0,10000):
       sum += num
       if num > 10000:
           print('This is the number you want ', num-1)
           break
```

Using while:

```
   sum = 0
   num = 0
   while sum < 10000:
        num += 1
        sum += num
   print('This is the number you want ', num-1)
```

Both of these print 140.

References:

- [When to use while loop rather than for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710601/when-to-use-while-loop-rather-than-for-loop)
- [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while)
- [More Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for)

Comment: You are my saviour! thank you for helping me find where I missed. I will make sure to define variables to start writing a code :)